# Help with a regular expression - Python

Tags: python, regex

Lets assume I have the following string:

```
string = "xxx abc123 xxx"
```

I want the regular expression to replace the digits in the string that begin with 'abc'. I have tried the following, but with no luck:

```
re.sub(r'\d{1,3}\babc','456',string)
```

Thanks.

Comment: What does your expected output for "xxx abc123 xxx" look like?

Comment: It should look like 'xxx abc456 xxx'

Comment: Is it always preceded by 'xxx abc'?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
re.sub(r'(?<=abc)\d{1,3}', '456', string)
```

Comment: Thank you. This has been very helpful. After doing some more research on this, I believe this expression is called a: positive lookbehind assertion.